# how to know what data has been sent to which map reduce job in hive?

Tags: mapreduce, hive

I am running a query let's say we have 1,2,3,4,5,1,2 in a column and i run a group by query along with order by which somehow cause 2 map reducer.

How can i know which mapper got what data.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an explain extended on the query to get query plan. It will give you details of each stages of the job.